# Practical Approach for getting maximum Power from a DC motor

Tags: dc-motor, efficiency

Theoretically, a DC Machine achieves its maximum Power when back emf is equal to half the applied voltage.

1. Why this condition is not realized in practice ?
2. What is the Practical Approach for getting maximum Power from DC machines ?

Comment: Run loaded so speed is 80% of free wheel speed... Works well most of the time for small DC motors in NY experience.

Comment: No!!! back-EMF = 50% at the maximum power transfer point, not maximum efficiency. Efficiency of an ideal motor at maximum power transfer is only 50% which is really rather poor, and most motors will be destroyed if you operate them there for a long time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

50% back-emf occurs at maximum *power output*, at which point the motor is slightly less than 50% efficient.

Why? Because at 50% rpm half the voltage going into the motor is being dropped across the resistance of the armature windings, so half the power is wasted. This becomes obvious when you look at the equivalent circuit of a DC motor. Here is an example:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8pFe6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Back-emf is caused by the armature spinning and generating a voltage which opposes the supply voltage. The rest of the supply voltage is dropped across Rm.

In this case back-emf is 3.5V, so Rm must have 7V-3.5V = 3.5V across it. 3.5V / 0.21Ω = 16.7A. 3.5V * 16.7A = 58.3W of 'copper' loss. 0.75A is used up in 'iron' losses, leaving 15.95A to produce output torque and power. 3.5V * 15.95A = 55.83W.

Efficiency = output power / input power. 55.83W / (7V * 16.7A) = 47.9% efficiency.

Maximum *efficiency* is achieved when copper loss equals iron loss. This usually occurs at around 80-90% of no-load rpm. If you know Io and Rm then calculating this point is simple.

Iron loss = Vm-(Io*Rm) * Io. In this case that works out to 5.13W. At peak efficiency copper loss is the same, so  Im<sup>2</sup> * Rm = 5.13W. Solving for Im we get 4.94A. Now calculate the voltage drop across Rm at this current, 4.94A * 0.21Ω = 1.04V. That leaves 5.96V for back-emf. Now calculate the no-load back-emf. Voltage drop across Rm is 0.75A * 0.21&ohm = 0.158V. 7V - 0.158V = 6.84V. 5.96V/6.84V = 87% of no-load rpm.

Here's an actual dyno test of the motor simulated above. Peak efficiency occurred at 5A (very close to the 4.94A we calculated) at 7360rpm. This is 86% of the no-load speed, 8550rpm.

You wouldn't want to run this motor at maximum power for long because it only weighs 50g. With over 50W of heat to get rid of it would quickly burn up. DC motors are generally operated somewhere *between* peak efficiency and maximum power output, as this provides the best compromise between power, efficiency, and size.

[image]

Comment: You write \$P_{iron loss} = (V-I_0R)I_0\$, but this makes it seem like iron losses are constant. I thought iron losses increase with speed, so shouldn't you model iron losses as: \$(V-IR)I_0\$ or just \$EI_0\$ ?? double comment for formatting

Comment: Io is not really a constant, but it is often close to constant over the _normal_ operating speed range of the motor ([example:](http://www.bhabbott.net.nz/EM300H.html)). These formulae are only approximations. To model **Io** accurately you would need to factor in hysteresis, eddy currents, brush/bearing friction and windage.

Answer (score 1):

Commutator DC motors are not used when efficiency is a high priority. They are used in situations where cost is a high priority and DC is the most readily available power source. They are used for auxiliary equipment in vehicles, for portable tools and appliances, as traction motors in small inexpensive vehicles like wheel chairs and golf carts and for toys. In many applications where commutator DC motors have been used, there is not much opportunity to operate the motors under the most efficient conditions because the applications require the motor to operate at a wide range of speeds and torques.

Where larger motors are required and it is economically attractive to optimize motor efficiency, more efficient types of motors are used. With efficient electronic controls, most other types of motors are more efficient than commutator DC motors. That includes brushless DC / permanent magnet synchronous motors, induction motors, wound rotor synchronous motors and reluctance motors.

In other words, "the Practical Approach for getting maximum Efficiency from DC machines" is to use another type of machine.

Answer (score 0):

A practical approach is the empirical one!  Couple the shafts of two identical motors together.  Apply and input voltage to one (motor) and a resistor on the other (generator).  Measure the input dc voltage/current and the output dc voltage/current.  Try different combinations of resistors and input voltages (which correlates to torque-speed, respectively).   Find the combo with the best Pin/Pout and that is maximum efficiency for that machine.